# Ito formula for $f(X_t, Y_{t-s})$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have a situation where I have two stochastic processes (say 2 OU processes) and I have the function $f(X_t, Y_{t-s})=\frac{X_t}{Y_{t-s}}$.

How do I apply Ito lemma in this case?(is Ito lemma still valid?)

This might be a very basic question for some of you here, so a reference would be enough if you can't be bothered to answer the question.
Thank you.

Edit: I forgot to mention that there is a relation between $X_t$ and $Y_t$ in the sense that their driving BMs are correlated.

Comment: There are several issues here and I'm wondering which one specifically you're worried about. The fact that f is a function of two variables? That's totally fine just use the multidimensinoal Ito's formula. The fact that f is not twice continuously differentiable at $y=0$? That could be a problem, maybe it's okay if $y \ne 0$ a.s.? I'm not certain. The fact that you're evaluating $Y$ at $t-s$? Should be fine if $s \ge 0$ since it will still be adapted.

Comment: The fact that concerns me is the $t-s$ part. Do I just apply Ito lemma  by pretending that $Y_{t-s}=Z_{t}$? The problem with this is that the SDE of $X_t$ has the drift and diffusion terms as functions of $Y_t$ (not $Y_{t-s}$).